# How to write the excel file multiple times without loading the data into memory?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am looking for a solution that will not cause a performance issue while writing to excel file using big data via openpyxl==2.6.4

- I have a big amount of data, and processing them recursively by 10k rows at time and appending to the file in order do not end up into memory issue

**Process is the following from the code below**

- create excel file with all headers, format headers with nice colors and add filters
- after starting recursive function to process 10k rows at time, and after each recursion to append data to the file was creating initially
- by appending data to excel file, it loads data in memory, want to escape this issue do not load but just to write without loading in the memory

I'm using *python==3.6* and *openpyxl==2.6.4*

**What I noticed:**

- writing multiple times in the same file openpyxl==2.6.4 is loading current data from the file in the memory and appending new data and writing again entire file, I do not want to load current data from file in the memory as I do not need to read them just to append new data to file
- same approach using simple csv is not loading in memory and getting the expected result, but there is possible to achieve same result with openpyxl as is nice formatted the file

The recursive process could repeat many times because had memory issues and came out recursively to process data with limit of 10k rows but writing to excel file via openpyxl, and performance issue is fixed and now openpyxl is loading in memory all data from file and causing same issue.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font, GradientFill, Border, Side
from openpyxl.styles.borders import BORDER_THIN
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

# 1 Step = creating the file with initial data, nice formatting the headers with colors

def make_intro_file(file_name, report_data):
    file = file_name + '.xlsx'
    if os.path.exists(file):
        os.remove(file)
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active

    ws_sheet = wb['Sheet']
    ws_sheet.title = report_data['description']['label']

    ws['A2'] = report_data['description']['label']
    ws['A2'].font = Font(bold=True)
    ws['A1'].fill = GradientFill(stop=("f2f2f2", "f2f2f2"))
    ws['A2'].fill = GradientFill(stop=("f2f2f2", "f2f2f2"))
    ws.merge_cells(start_row=2, start_column=1, end_row=2, end_column=len(report_data['fields']))
    ws.merge_cells(start_row=1, start_column=1, end_row=1, end_column=len(report_data['fields']))
    ws['A3'] = '%s - %s' % (report_data['timestamp']['start'], report_data['timestamp']['end'])
    ws['A3'].fill = GradientFill(stop=("f2f2f2", "f2f2f2"))
    ws['A4'].fill = GradientFill(stop=("f2f2f2", "f2f2f2"))
    ws.merge_cells(start_row=3, start_column=1, end_row=3, end_column=len(report_data['fields']))
    ws.merge_cells(start_row=4, start_column=1, end_row=4, end_column=len(report_data['fields']))

    ws.append(report_data['fields'])
    for cell in ws["5:5"]:
        cell.font = Font(bold=True)
        cell.fill = GradientFill(stop=("edcb7b", "edcb7b"))
        cell.border = Border(
                left=Side(border_style=BORDER_THIN, color='e1b03e'),
                right=Side(border_style=BORDER_THIN, color='e1b03e'),
                top=Side(border_style=BORDER_THIN, color='e1b03e'),
                bottom=Side(border_style=BORDER_THIN, color='e1b03e')
            )

    ws.auto_filter.ref = "A5:" + get_column_letter(ws.max_column) + str(ws.max_row)
    column_widths = []
    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for i, cell in enumerate(row):
            try:
                column_widths[i] = max(column_widths[i], len(str(cell.value)))
            except IndexError:
                column_widths.append(len(str(cell.value)))

    for i, column_width in enumerate(column_widths):
        ws.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(i + 1)].width = 20
    wb.save(file)

# 2 Step - recursive function to process each time 10k rows and once processed each time 10k appending to the file created in 1 Step
def __get(self, cursor):
    // select by 10k raws each time
    response = select_data_from_mysql(cursor)
    // process data and changing data
    data = self.__write_response(response, cursor)
    if len(response) == self.limit:
        self.__get(cursor)
    return data

# here receiving data from recursive function and appending processed data to the excel file
def __write_response(self, response):
    self.generate_report(file_name, data, self.headers)

# here i am just writing the data received from above
# ISSUE: load_workbook is loading in the memory all data in file and writing again entire file
def generate_report(self, file_name, data, headers):
    file = file_name + '.xlsx'
    wb = load_workbook(file)
    ws = wb.active
    for r in data:
        values = (r[k] for k in headers)
        ws.append(values)
    wb.save(file)
```

**Desired result:**

- just to open the file and write data to excel without loading current data from file in the memory

**Tried using csv file**

- is not loading in memory but just appending to the file, that is what I am looking for, but the excel file is nice formatted and looking if can be achieved same result as csv

Comment: Have you looked at write-only mode?

Comment: @CharlieClark yes i saw the docs, but did not manage to get it working and was no example using the customization i did, formatting with colors the cells

Comment: Formatting is tricky but the documentation shows how to do it using WriteOnlyCells.

Comment: @CharlieClark can u help to transfer the code with write only mode? i think only the function generate_report should be changed?